# Detect if ADB server is running on Android?

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to detect if the `adb server` is running on the Android device for part of an anti-cheating implementation for my free game.

Specifically, I want to stop use of `adb shell input tap x,y`, since the game is a competitive multiplayer puzzle game.

Things I have tried:

1. Using battery info I can detect if USB is plugged in.  Well, that is also a legit use.
2. Using `Settings.Secure` or `Settings.Global`, I can query `ADB_ENABLED`, but that always returns `1` if adb is enabled.  It DOES NOT take into account adb connected or not!
3. Querying all system services, but I cannot see anything that looks like an adb service.

At this point, I am out of ideas.  Hopefully someone else knows how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check for running `adbd` process or query `init.svc.adbd` system property:

```
$ ps adbd
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
root      14947 1     4596   208   ffffffff 00019358 S /sbin/adbd

$ getprop init.svc.adbd
running
```

In Android the `adb` driver is implemented as a function of universal `usb` driver. You can check the (comma separated) list of currently enabled `usb` functions to see if it includes `"adb"`:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/virtual/android_usb/android0/functions
mtp,adb
```

But you would not be able stop cheating while your app is running completely on the user controlled device.

Comment: Awesome... thanks!  Stopping cheating is easy in this case... just don't submit the score to the servers if the adb is running :)

Comment: Followup:  you can check MotionEvent.getDeviceId() ... it returns zero for input by the adb!

Comment: **All 3 methods here will not tell you whether a device is connected to a PC actively running `adb`.** Just disconnected my device, and running all commands in an on-device terminal emulator shows `adb` is still running.